# Unable to deploy Unity3d project on iPhone device because of linking errors

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, unity-game-engine

I have created a xcode project using unity3d tool, while building the project for iOS my Player settings are like this:

```
1. Target Device: iPhone Only
2. Target Platform: Universal armv6+armv7 (OpenGL ES1.1+2.0) & I have tried it with armv6(OpenGL ES1.1)
3. SDK Version: iOS 4.3 & I have tried it with iOS Latest
4. Target iOS Version: 4.0
Api Compatibility Level: .Net 2.0 Subset, when I am trying to run it in iPhone I am getting the below mentioned error:
```

> "__GetLookupStatus", referenced from:
>
> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6: "__GetLookupStatus", referenced from: __Z19RegisterMonoModulesv in RegisterMonoModules.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**& my Unity 3 version is 3.4.2f3 & my Xcode version is 4.2.1.**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try it with armv7 only as target platform? Maybe this an option for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is working now. I forgot to add my Objevtive-c files into Xcode project.